# What is the best way to do string manipulation in a shell script?

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell

I have a path as a string in a shell-script, could be absolute or relative:

/usr/userName/config.cfg

or

../config.cfg

I want to extract the file name (part after the last /, so in this case: "config.cfg")

I figure the best way to do this is with some simple regex?
Is this correct?  Should or should I use sed or awk instead?

Shell-scripting's string manipulation features seem pretty primative by themselves, and appear very esoteric.

Any example solutions are also appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of string manipulation I'd just use

```
file=`basename "$filename"`
```

**Edit**:

Thanks to unwind for some newer syntax for this (which assumes your filename is held in $filename):

```
file=$(basename $filename)
```

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend the newer syntax: "file=$(basename $filename)" assuming $filename holds the input name.

Comment: @unwind. Thanks for this I wasn't aware of that syntax. Is it just preferred now (but essentially the same) or is it quicker?

Comment: I think it's preferred as considered more readable, but that's all

Comment: The $() construct works in modern shells like ksh and bash, but I don't think it's strict POSIX sh. It would be a mistake to use it in a /bin/sh script, though it would still work in most systems (as it's usually a symlnk to bash)

Comment: If your script does this (very) often, you will see a significant speed-up with the new syntax as your script doesn't have to shell out to determine the base name.

Comment: Why on earth waste a million CPU cycles for a fork to `basename`? The basename is simply `${filename##*/}`. **That is the best way**. This answer is about the worst.

Comment: @guns The `$()` is POSIX, but since SunOS and Solaris `/bin/sh` are not POSIX shells (as opposed to /usr/xpg4/bin/sh) they only understand backticks.

Answer (score 11):

If you're okay with using bash, you can use bash string expansions:

```
FILE="/path/to/file.example"
FILE_BASENAME="${FILE##*/}"
```

It's a little cryptic, but the braces start the variable expansion, and the double hash does a greedy removal of the specified glob pattern from the beginning of the string.

Double %% does the same thing from the end of a string, and a single percent or hash does a non-greedy removal.

Also, a simple replace construct is available too:

```
FILE=${FILE// /_}
```

would replace all spaces with underscores for instance.

A single slash again, is non-greedy.

Comment: +1. this solution is much faster than executing external command, but as guns mentioned, you should use `#!/bin/bash` in such case.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation of Double Hash / Double Percent greedy  guys and their single Hash / Percent non-greedy. That's good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Most environments have access to [`perl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) and I'm more comfortable with that for most string manipulation.

But as mentioned, from something this simple, you can use [`basename`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/basename/).

Answer (score 1):

I typically use sed with a simple regex, like this:

```
echo "/usr/userName/config.cfg" | sed -e 's+^.*/++'
```

result:

```
>echo "/usr/userName/config.cfg" | sed -e 's+^.*/++'
config.cfg
```